# Convert list of strings to list of simple objects

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to pass json to the controller in MVC. My method returns a list of strings, which is then translated to json with array of strings. Because of some front end complexities I should return the result as array of basic objects e.g. instead of `["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]` etc. i need to pass `[{item: "Item1"}, {item: "Item2"}, {item: "Item3"}]`.

I created something that works, but it would require a lot of repetition. I was wondering if there was already something built-in, or just a better logic to accomplish such tasks.

A new super basic class:

```
public class ObjectConverted
{
    public string item { get; set; }
}
```

A converter class:

```
public class Converter 
{ 
    public List<ObjectConverted> convertToObjects(IEnumerable<string> listOfStrings)
    {
        List<ObjectConverted> listConverted = new List<ObjectConverted>();
        foreach (string i in listOfStrings)
        {
            ObjectConverted oc = new ObjectConverted();
            oc.item = i;
            listConverted.Add(oc);
        }
        return listConverted;
    }
}
```

and pass it to the controller like:

```
public ActionResult Competitors()
{
    IEnumerable<string> strings = getItemStrings();
    Converter c = new Converter();
    List<ObjectConverted> objects = c.convertToObjects(strings);

    return Json(objects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about converting it into linq which returns anonymous class?

```
public ActionResult Competitors()
{
    return Json(getItemStrings().Select(x => new { Item = x }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Great, this line works exactly the same as mine 20+:) Thank you!